# "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Tags: java, angular, spring, http, cors

I've made an angular application with typescript code that uses a java spring web service, I'm having trouble with CORS.

The first http request gets an access token from the web server to use in all following requests, but all following requests are refused with this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at X from origin Y has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

X is the URL resource of my http method
Y is the origin of the request

**API GATEWAY MODULE**

```java
package it.sitgeo.apigateway.controller;

import it.sitgeo.apigateway.exception.LoginException;
import it.sitgeo.apigateway.model.AppUser;
import it.sitgeo.apigateway.model.LoginForm;
import it.sitgeo.apigateway.service.AppUserService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sitgeo")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "*")
public class AppUserController {

    private final AppUserService service;

    @PostMapping(path = "/login", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
    MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<String> login (@Valid @ModelAttribute LoginForm loginForm) throws LoginException   {    
        String access_token = service.login(loginForm.getUsername(), loginForm.getPassword());
        if(access_token == null){ 
            throw new LoginException("Le credenziali inserite non sono corrette");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(access_token);
    }
```

---

**PED MODULE**

```java
package it.sitgeo.ped.Controllers;

import it.sitgeo.ped.Entities.*;
import it.sitgeo.ped.Repositories.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sitgeo/PED")
@AllArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost","Y"} ,allowedHeaders = "*")
public class PEDController {

    final EmailConfiguration emailConfiguration;
    private  final PraticaRepository praticaRepository;
    private final ComuneRepository comuneRepository;

    private final TitolareRepository titolareRepository;
    private final PdfRepository pdfRepository;

    private final ProcuratoreRepository procuratoreRepository;

    private final DomicilioElettronicoRepository domicilioElettronicoRepository;

    private final LocalizzazioneRepository localizzazioneRepository;

    private final CatastoRepository catastoRepository;

    private final TecnicoRepository tecnicoRepository;

    private final SoggettiTitolariRepository soggettiTitolariRepository;

    private final StatoUnitaRepository statoUnitaRepository;

    private final TipologiaRepository tipologiaRepository;

  

   //@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")

    @GetMapping("/getCOMUNI/{provincia}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getComuni(@PathVariable String provincia) {
        log.info("getCOMUNI {}", provincia);
        ResponseEntity<?> response;
        try {
            response = new ResponseEntity<String[]>(comuneRepository.searchComuneByProvincia(provincia),
HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response = new ResponseEntity<String[]>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        return response;
    }
```

---

*PED MODULE*

```java
package it.sitgeo.ped.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CORSConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("Y", "http://localhost")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD","OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

I've tried this http method using postman and it works as intended returning a JSON.

Comment: when you specify your origin Y in `.allowedOrigins()` are you including the port number as well?

Comment: is there a java equivalent of `.AllowCredentials()` that we have in c#?

Comment: I tried to include the port number and insert allowCredentials but it still doesn’t work